# Git custom commands from PATH not working

Tags: linux, bash, git

I have `~/bin/git-continue` and `~/bin/git-abort` script, which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

repo_path=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit $?
fi

if [ -d "${repo_path}/rebase-merge" ]; then
    git rebase --continue
elif [ -d "${repo_path}/rebase-apply" ]; then
    git rebase --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/MERGE_HEAD" ]; then
    git merge --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD" ]; then
    git cherry-pick --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/REVERT_HEAD" ]; then
    git revert --continue
else
    echo "No something in progress?"
fi
```

I also put the directory `~/bin` to `PATH` by putting this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
[[ ":$PATH:" != *":~/bin:"* ]] && PATH="~/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

So, I checked that `$ git-continue` works fine, but `git continue` outputs following error:
`git: 'continue' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

What can I look for possible cause of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PATH` contains unexpanded `~/bin`. Your shell understands what `~/` means but `git` apparently doesn't. You should include full path to `~/bin` in your `PATH`.

If you used `PATH=~/"bin:${PATH}"` instead of `PATH="~/bin:${PATH}"`, tilde expansion would occur and `PATH` would store the expanded path. But there's a problem with `:~/bin:` inside `[[ ]]`. Not quoting tilde is not the only condition (see "Tilde Expansion" in `man 1 bash`), this makes expanding `:~/bin:` difficult. And you need to expand it to test against the full path in `PATH`.

It's easier to use `$HOME`:

```
[[ ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/bin:"* ]] && PATH="$HOME/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

`$HOME` gets expanded before the whole string is assigned to the `PATH` variable. This means `PATH` now contains the *full* path to your `$HOME/bin`. `git` will understand this path.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Thank you for pointing out the difference of string path and just path.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [custom alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) in order to work around this. Using an alias might be preferable because it will be easier to debug for someone who isn't aware of your customization and you are currently not handling anything in your command but rather just want to run a series of commands.

See also [How to embed bash script directly inside a git alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309430/how-to-embed-bash-script-directly-inside-a-git-alias) on StackOverflow.

For anyone interested, it seems like the only documentation for this behavior currently is in the [source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/041f5ea1cf987a4068ef5f39ba0a09be85952064/git.c#L667) as per [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978257/extending-git-functionality) and [git-scm issue](https://github.com/git/git-scm.com/issues/744).

Comment: If you want to complain that something is not correct give me a chance to improve it by actually telling me what isn't correct. Does the approach of creating an alias not work? Would it not be a solution to the problem? Is cmd-something working to create additional parameters the default behavior on linux? Did anyone provide a source on this being the default behavior for git? There are blog posts on this but the only real documentation seems to be "it's in the source". Debugging wise and portability wise using an alias would probably be preferable. Especially since he has no options.

Comment: The sentence you removed was not correct. So it’s all good now. No, this is not a Linux thing. It’s a Git thing. Unfortunately, I was not able to find authoritative documentation about this.